# programar una condición por atributo de producto

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Tengo una tarea algo complicada y no encuentro la forma. Espero que alguien me pueda ayudar.

Resulta que estoy trabajando en una tienda en woocommerce la cual tiene a los "proveedores" como atributo de producto.[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Me pidieron que dependiendo del proveedor, se le muestre al cliente un mensaje similar al que se ve en la imagen, pero dando el tiempo de entrega de este. Por ejemplo, el proveedor de este producto es "BGC", y se requiere que todos los productos que tenga el proveedor **"BGC"**, apareza el mensaje **"Entrega de 3 a 5 días hábiles"**
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En esta sección, tengo desarrollados estos mensajes con diferentes configuraciones dependiendo de la categoría del producto.

```
<?php if ( has_term('ingredientes', 'product_cat' )) :?>
        <div class="col-4 col-sm-6 order-2">
            <div class="benefits__item align-items-center pb-2">
                <div class="benefits__wrapper-img">
                    <img loading="lazy" width="68" height="52" src="<?= get_stylesheet_directory_uri() ?>/assets/images/svg/Devoluciones.svg" class="svg d-block benefits__img" alt="Servicio al cliente 24 horas">
                </div>
                <p class="benefits__label pr-md-5">Devolución hasta 30 días</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    <?php endif;?>
```

Por ejemplo, en el anterior código, lo que hace es que le muestra al cliente que este **producto tiene 30 días de devolución**, por pertenecer a la categoría de "Ingredientes". Pero no he podido desarrollar un tipo de condición similar, utilizando los atributos de "proveedor" o "marca".

Espero que alguien me pueda ayudar con esto. Se lo agradecería en absoluto.

Comment: No entiendo tu pregunta. ¿`proveedor` y `marca` deben mostrar el mismo mensaje que `ingredientes`? Si es así, entonces pon algo como: `if ( has_term('ingredientes', 'product_cat' ) || has_term( 'proveedor', 'product_cat' ) || has_term( 'marca', 'product_cat' ) )` En cambio, si es un contenido nuevo, haz un `if` parecido, poniendo dentro el contenido que deba llevar.

Comment: Al parecer no has leído bien mi documentación. "marca" y "proveedor" no son categorías, son **atributos**. por ende, "product_cat" no aplica. Y no quiero que aparezcan, lo que estoy buscando es, si el producto pertenece a uno de esos atributos, muestre un mensaje

Comment: Una disculpa, no me fijé en ese detalle. En el contexto de WooCommerce puedes usar: `wc_get_product`, suponiendo que tienes una referencia al producto en este contexto. Por ejemplo: `if ($producto->get_attribute('proveedor') { // Tiene ese atributo, poner el contenido aquí }` [Fuente](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13454788/5587982).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No estoy seguro de si hay formas más elegantes de hacer esto, pero yo lo haría de esta forma.

```
// Obtenemos la global $product
    global $product;

    // Obtenemos todos los attributos
    $attributes = $product->get_attributes();

    // Creamos unos arrays vacios
    $proveedor = array();
    $marca = array();

    // Verificamos si hay attributos
    if ( $attributes ) :
        foreach ( $attributes as $attribute ) {
            
            // Verificamos si el attributo actual es de tipo Proveedor
            if ( $attribute['name'] == 'proveedor' ):
            
                // Obtenemos los Proveedores
                $terms = $attribute->get_terms();

                // Si hay proveedores agregados los agregamos a nuestro array de Proveedores
                if ( $terms ) :
                    foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
                        array_push( $proveedor, $term->name );
                    }
                endif;

            endif;

            // Verificamos si el attributo actual es de tipo Marca
            if ( $attribute['name'] == 'marca' ):
            
                // Obtenemos las Marcas
                $terms = $attribute->get_terms();

                // Si hay Marcas agregadas las agregamos a nuestro array de Marcas
                if ( $terms ) :
                    foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
                        array_push( $marca, $term->name );
                    }
                endif;

            endif;

        }
    endif;


    // Asi verificamos si existe un proveedor especifico
    if ( in_array( 'Proveedor 1', $proveedor ) ) :
        echo 'Tu Mensaje';
    endif;

    // Asi verificamos si existe una Marca especifico
    if ( in_array( 'Marca 1', $marca ) ) :
        echo 'Tu Mensaje';
    endif;

    // Asi verificamos un proveedor y una marca
    if ( in_array( 'Proveedor 1', $proveedor ) && in_array( 'Marca 1', $marca ) ) :
        echo 'Tu Mensaje';
    endif;
```

Aquí lo que hago es obtener primero la variable global $product, para obtener todos los datos del producto.

Luego obtengo todos los atributos usando `get_attributes()` y comienzo a recorrer todos los atributos, una vez los recorro proceso a clasificarlos por tipo dentro de un array por cada Atributo.

Ahora que tengo un array con todos mis proveedores y todas las marcas asignadas a mi producto solo verifico con `in_array()` si existe un termino dentro de mis atributos y muestro un mensaje según sea necesario.

Comment: Hola Jefferzon. Gracias por tu ayuda. Esto si me debe servir.

Comment: @JonTMarz Genial, si te funciona no olvides marcarla como aceptada y darle un voto.

Answer (score 0):

Si `proveedor` y `marca` deben mostrar el mismo mensaje que `ingredientes`, simplemente incluye esa posibilidad usando [el operador OR (`||`)](https://www.php.net/manual/es/language.operators.logical.php) de este modo:

```
<?php if ( has_term('ingredientes', 'product_cat') || has_term('proveedor', 'product_cat') || has_term('marca', 'product_cat') ) :?>
        <div class="col-4 col-sm-6 order-2">
            <div class="benefits__item align-items-center pb-2">
                <div class="benefits__wrapper-img">
                    <img loading="lazy" width="68" height="52" src="<?= get_stylesheet_directory_uri() ?>/assets/images/svg/Devoluciones.svg" class="svg d-block benefits__img" alt="Servicio al cliente 24 horas">
                </div>
                <p class="benefits__label pr-md-5">Devolución hasta 30 días</p>
            </div>
        </div>
<?php endif;?>
```

En cambio, si `proveedor` y `marca` deben tener otra cosa, lo mismo, pero sólo con ellas dos:

```
<?php if ( has_term('proveedor', 'product_cat') || has_term('marca', 'product_cat') ) :?>
        
    <!-- Define aquí el contenido, como haces más arriba -->

<?php endif;?>
```

Y si cada una debe llevar su propio contenido:

```
<?php if ( has_term('proveedor', 'product_cat') ) :?>
        
    <!-- Define aquí el contenido para proveedor -->

<?php endif;?>
```

Y:

```
<?php if ( has_term('marca', 'product_cat') ) :?>
        
    <!-- Define aquí el contenido para marca -->

<?php endif;?>
```

Comment: marca y proveedor no son categorías, son atributos. Si fueran categorías, tendría todo resuelto, porque si me funciona con ingredientes, funcionaría con cualquier categoría. Te agradezco, pero tu ayuda no aplica en este caso.

Answer (score 0):

Para los que visiten este post. Me ha funcionado de esta forma

```
global $product;
$proveedor = $product->get_attribute( 'Proveedor' ); // Aqui llamo el atributo proveedor
$proveedores = array('BGC', 'Oster'); // aquí coloco los proveedores a quienes aplica y en el siguiente condicional pinta en pantalla si se está llamando al atributo. Si no lo llama, no lo muestra
    if(in_array($proveedor, $proveedores)) : ?>
        <div class="col-4 col-sm-6 order-2">
            <div class="benefits__item align-items-center pb-2">
                <div class="benefits__wrapper-img">
                    <img loading="lazy" width="68" height="52" src="<?= get_stylesheet_directory_uri() ?>/assets/images/svg/Entrega-gratis.svg" class="svg d-block benefits__img" alt="Servicio de entrega a domicilio">
                </div>
        <?php // Con un switch recorro los proveedores y aplico el texto adecuado
switch ($proveedor) : 
                case('BGC') :
                        echo '<p class="benefits__label pr-md-5">Entrega de 3</br> a 5 días hábiles</p>';
                    break;
                    case('Oster') :
                        echo '<p class="benefits__label pr-md-5">Entrega de 5</br> a 7 días hábiles</p>';
                    break;
                    endswitch;
                    ?>
                </div>
            </div>
        <?php endif; ?>
```